# What are the main technologies needed to build an AI for Warcraft 3's mod DotA?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, game-ai, applications

What are the main technologies needed to build an AI for Warcraft 3's mod Defense of the Ancients (DotA)? Maybe I can take inspiration from OpenAI's work.